# How to open a fragment on click of a button?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hey Guys I know its very silly question but i'm facing it from last few days

This is my click event

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment newCase = new NewCase();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // What to put in the ? marked argument?
        //What is fragment container id?
        transaction.replace(?, newCase );    

        transaction.addToBackStack(null);          
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

And this is my fragment class

```
public class NewCase extends Fragment {}
```

Now let me know how to open fragment class with xml view in android?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to appear the `NewCase` `Fragment` entire portion of the activity layout after clicking on the `fab` ?

Comment: yeah I want to appear entire portion of fragment over my activity

Comment: i see the answer is written in your code :D ; please give me a while i am demonstrating a solution

Comment: brother its not replacing. its show me error in transaction.replace...!!!

Comment: are you sure you have a container `layout` in your activity `layout` ?

Comment: nop I'vent defined any class related to fragment in my activity

Comment: What error? please [edit] your question with the exact phrase shown to you

Comment: Also, you should probably be using `getSupportFragmentManager` if using `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: I want to open my fragment class and also want to close my present activity class. Its just like opening one xml file and closing second xml file. The following answer are not showing any error but it also not open my my fragment class as well @cricket_007

Comment: Yeah Im using AppCompatActivity

Comment: If those answers don't work, why did you accept them? Also a Fragment needs an Activity, you aren't switching anything, really, just loading a sub-view.

Comment: Hopefully this clears anything up... The import statement of the Fragment class matters... https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments

Comment: Ok I'll go through your link. Btw again thx for your help for this question N pervious question as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `activity_layout.xml` you should add  a `linearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

 </LinearLayout>
```

Then the rest is up to your code

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view){    
    Fragment newCase=new NewCase();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,newCase); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
    transaction.commit();

}
});
```

**Notice** the `Layout` id in the xml and containe id same

Answer (score 1):

As you going to show a fragment not activity, right? then why should you use `startActivity()`.

You can try it

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){    
        Fragment newCase=new NewCase();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.your_fragment_container,newCase); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
        transaction.commit();

    }
});
```

Here `R.id.your_fragment_container` will be replaced with the id of the layout inside which you are going to place your fragment.

For example-
**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</FrameLayout>
```

then you will use

```
transaction.replace(R.id.frag_container,newCase);
```

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newcase, container, false);

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.newcase, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this,view);

Comment: Great. hope it fills your requirement? :)

Comment: @Cool why did you copy your Fragment code into a comment? The container is any `ViewGroup` within the Activity layout. Most people use FrameLayout for Fragments