# How can I open fragment from onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to open a fragment form onClick in my recyclerview adapter and pass data. I know how open a activity(check the code below), but how can i open fragment same way. Check the code below for better understanding. I am new to android and trying to learn from free resource. Sorry if anything is wrong.

CODE

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            PlaylistDetailsItem playlistDetailsItems = this.playlistDetailsItems.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, VideoActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("videoHeading", playlistDetailsItems.getPlaylistDetailsSnippet()
                    .getPlaylistDetailsTitle());

            intent.putExtra("videoDesc", playlistDetailsItems.getPlaylistDetailsSnippet()
                    .getPlaylistDetailsDescription());

            intent.putExtra("videoID", playlistDetailsItems.getPlaylistDetailsSnippet()
                    .getPlaylistDetailsResourceId().getVideoId());

            this.context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42055690/2979171. Check this, and for sending data you can use constructor

Comment: I am using it in recyclerview adapter and getFragmentManager() says cannot resolvemethod 'getFragmentManager'

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your onClick

```
 FirstFragment firstFrag = new FirstFragment();
 this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.layout_container, firstFrag, TAG_FRAGMENT)
      .addToBackStack(null)
      .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    replaceFragmentInternal(new fragment,b,true,false);
```

//Put data in bundle and pass it in method. Use this method in Top Level Activity so that you don't have to write same code again and again.

```
replaceFragmentInternal(Fragment fragment, Bundle bundle, boolean addToBackStack, boolean anim) {
        if (bundle != null)
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        tag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        //ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        ft.replace(R.id.container_internal, fragment, tag);
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);

        if (addToBackStack)
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);

        try {
            ft.commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of All you have to create a Fragment Class Like this and remember to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; (support v4 fragment)

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_file, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

}

And call fragment like

```
    MyFragment myfragment = new Fragment();

//pass data
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("KEY","DATA");
        myfragment.setArguments(bundle);

     FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

                fragmentManager.addToBackStack(null);

            fragmentManager.replace(R.id.content, mFragment, TAG).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create Viewholder if No, then paste below inside your adapter of recycler view at the end before closing the adapter( before bottom "}" )

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        mIdView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        mContentView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);

        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (null != listener) {     
                    listener.onListFragmentInteraction(mValues.get(position));
                }
           }
    });
}
```

Also read this tutorial for sending data: 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

All this looks preatty hard, but it this is for learning and also looks professional